# Loading different images in the listview item for custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

Hi please forgive me if I am mistaking when explaining the problem . I have a Custom Base adapter in which there is two imageView and two TextView and I am usning an Async task to set the image from the URL. it sets the image but changes the image again automatically.

below is the code for the adapter .

```
public class SharedPhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private static final String BRANCH="Branch";
private static final String DATE="DateTime";
private static final String STARS="Stars";
private static final String IMAGE_URL="URL";
private static final String USER_NAME="UserName";
 TextView name,date,comment;
 ImageView pro_image,shared_image;

 public SharedPhotosAdapter(Context con,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

     context=con;
     data=result;
     inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     ViewHolder holder;
     Bitmap bitmap=null;
     ImageView image = null;
     HashMap<String, String> result=data.get(position);
    if(rowView==null)
    {
        rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.shared_photos_item, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();


    holder.name=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.date=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    holder.comment=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    holder.pro_image=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.shared_image=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);






    rowView.setTag(holder);


    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();

    }

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.shared_image).execute(result.get(IMAGE_URL));
    holder.name.setText(result.get(USER_NAME));
    holder.date.setText(result.get(DATE));
    holder.comment.setText(result.get(BRANCH));





    return rowView;
}



public class ViewHolder
{
     TextView name,date,comment;
     ImageView pro_image,shared_image;


}


}
```

Here is the Async task that i am using for setting the image from the url

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
      InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
      mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
 }
}
```

it setting randomly any image to the image view just cant figure out where i am going wrong.
 A  little help will be appreciable.

thanks

Comment: long story short: use some image loader library for android ... long story: ListView is reusing item, in getView you are starting AsyncTask, you scroll listview, now row view initialy associated to fx.: item with id=3 is now associated to item with id=15, AsyncTask finish and put image from item with id=3 to image view ...

Comment: Agreed. Your approach is flawed because `ListView`s etc will re-use the `ImageView`s and you have to cancel tasks that were started for an image previously used in the same `ImageView`. You should also have some caching so you don't download the images over and over. There are lots of tiny details you have to get right to make it work and libraries like UniversalImageLoader or Volley can do that for you.

Comment: You don't retain the image fetched anywhere, so as you scroll you will be fetching the same image over and over again.  If the view has a valid 'holder', it will likely contain an image fetched earlier that was associated with a row that is no longer visible.  At a minimum, you should set holder.sharedImage=null, in your getView method,prior to starting the async task.  But the real fix would be to use an image loader, which will keep track of which images it has already downloaded, and then you can simply assign holder.sharedImage to that image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to remove the hassle of downloading images/caching etc.
Once you have the jar in your workspace, all you need to do in the getView() method of the adapter class is this.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(result.get(IMAGE_URL)).into(holder.shared_image);
```

No need of the DownloadAsyncTask.
As @zapl also suggested in the comment, there are other libraries like Volley and UniversalImageLoader, but I liked Picasso. You can also easily apply transformations like rounded-image using the Transformation interface provided by Picasso.

Comment: @droidx can I use getActivity()).load(imageURL) in place of (context).load(result.get(IMAGE_URL))? Will that do the job?